# Pygame choose color NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a question about pygame. I saw many people can choose their color by just typing the color, like `screen.fill(white)`. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")


gameExit = False
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

However, I get this error:

```
 NameError: name 'white' is not defined
```

Moreover, I remember there is another way to do so, like `pygame.COLOR("white")`

Comment: why not? where you define `white` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the colors, by typing at the beginning of the project: `white=(255,255,255)` or `black=(0,0,0)`. This sets the both variables `white` and `black` to the colors `(255,255,255)` and `(0,0,0)`. The programs you saw, had these functions in the project, otherwise the `screen.fill(white)` wouldn't work. See http://www.discoveryplayground.com/computer-programming-for-kids/rgb-colors/ for help.

Answer (score 0):

As has been said, you have not defined the variable 'white' that you are trying to use variables for the colors are not automatically defined, though there are predefined colors that you can look up by their name. You have to pick out the ones you want to use in your program.

Some are very obvious and you can grab them easily like this:

```
white = pygame.Color("white")
```

Others are not as obvious and you have to find the string name you want. I often find myself trying to find color names and find this snippet very handy:

```
import pygame
from pprint import  pprint

color_list = [ (c, v) for c, v in pygame.color.THECOLORS.items() if 'slategrey' in c]
pprint(color_list)
```

which outputs:

```
[('darkslategrey', (47, 79, 79, 255)),
 ('slategrey', (112, 128, 144, 255))
 ('lightslategrey', (119, 136, 153, 255))]
```

I do that in an interactive session to get all the names that include 'slategrey' and then in my actual code I can use the one I want like this:

```
slategrey = pygame.Color("slategrey")
```

and then later in the code reference it like this:

```
screen.fill(slategrey,  pygame.Rect(  0, 0, 100, 100))
```